# How to "catch" console.error()? (SO title)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I included a lib that uses `console.error()` instead of `throw`.

Because of this, my `try...catch` doesn't work. And because it's a 3rd party lib, I can't change their code.

Is there a (preferably elegant) workaround to "catch" a `console.error()`?

Comment: You could try to replace the global `console` object, but oh boy is that a yucky and potentially error prone workaround…

Comment: Fix the lib and submit a pull request?

Comment: Which library is it, and where is the error statement in its code? There may be another way

Answer (score 3):

You cannot catch something that doesn't throw any errors.
It looks like a crutch but you can override your console.error method in the code below. But don't forget that after you will have overriden console.error that throws errors!!!

```js
console.errorWithoutExceptions = console.error;
console.error = (...messages) => {
    console.errorWithoutExceptions(...messages); 
    throw new Error(messages[0]);
}

// now you can use 
try {
   // your code
   console.error('test error');
} catch(e) {
   // process you error with message 'test error' here
}

// don't forget to restore previous console.error after using
console.error = console.errorWithoutExceptions;
```

Comment: Important gotcha: this approach won't work if the thing you are doing is asynchronous or may call other code though callbacks because then while it's running any other unrelated console error will also throw. Better to filter the message to identify known errors before attempting to throw them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and manipulate the global console object to your requirement. But that's messy and might generate additional errors.

More here : [Console | Node.js Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_class_console)